# Validate POST request Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation, laravel-5.5

I validate POST request like:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "id.*" => 'required|integer'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors, 400);
        }

        echo "Ok";
```

When I send request without parameter `id` it skips validation and returns `echo "Ok";`.

Why validation does not work?

Comment: Why are you using `id.*`? Have you tried just `id`?

Comment: What do you expect normally send as `id` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expect `id` is array of integers you should update validation rules like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "id" => 'required|array',
            "id.*" => 'integer'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First know when using $request->validate(); when it fail exceptions are raised!
And they are automatically handled by laravel. If it's a **get**, or a **normal post form,** then **the process will redirect back to the form**.

To note, when using the validate method during an **AJAX** request, Laravel will not generate a redirect response. **Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.**

If you want to not have such an automatic behavior, cr**eate manually a validator**, then **you can check with ->fails() method**, as the example show bellow. That's can be handful in a lot of situations.

```
<?php 
public function store(Request $request)

        {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
                'body' => 'required',
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return redirect('post/create')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
            }

            // Store the blog post...
        }
    }
```

And there is no better then the doc itself: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation
there is a lot of options, to personalize our validation process.